Exponential Limit Estimation
Background: this came from a casual discussion about the compound interest problem.
Consider the function $f(a,b),a\in\Bbb N, b\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ where
$f(0,b)=1+\frac{1}{b}$,
for $a\neq 0$, $f(a,b)=f(a-1,b)^{f(a-1,b)}$
Question: What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n,n)$? What is the speed of convergence w.r.t. $n$, i.e. $O(|f(n,n)-\lim_{m\to \infty}f(m,m)|)$?
My attempt:
The Mathematica code below should calculate the desired function correctly:
Seq = {};
For[n = 10, n <= 10000, n = n + 50,
  temp = 1 + 1/n;
  
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   temp = Power[N[temp, 20], N[temp, 20]];
   ];
  
  AppendTo[Seq, {n, temp}];
  ];
ListPlot[Seq]

which gives $f(n,n)$ w.r.t. $n$: 
And hence I highly suspect that it converges. Taking $g(a,b)=\ln f(a,b)$ just gives $g(a,b)=g(a-1,b)\exp g(a-1,b)$ which does not quite simplify the structure.

by trial an error I tried $f(x)=10.4/\ln(x)$ and kind a suits (I look for $a/\ln(3000) = 1.3\Rightarrow a\approx 10.4$ from the points in the graph)... Did you tried it?

My computer calculations suggest that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n,n)=1$.

This is quite an interesting function. When you take it's natural logarithm, you get a tower of fractals.

I suspect it goes to 1

I do not have the strength to write what would be needed, but I got $$\ln f(3,b) = (e^k)^{e^k} * e^k * k$$ and $$\ln f(4,b) = (e^k)^{{(e^k)}^{{(e^k)}^{e^k}}} * (e^k)^{e^k} * e^k * k$$ where $$k=(1+\frac{1}{b})\ln(1+\frac{1}{b})$$ I doubt this pattern is very hard to prove using induction, and once that is done, if $b\to\infty$ then $k\to0$ and hence $\ln f(n,n) \to 0$ from which we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,n) = 1$$
Edit: I realized the pattern might be hard to see from just two examples, so the pattern is that the highest tower has $2^{n-2}$ terms for $f(n,b)$, and the towers after that have $2^{n-3}, 2^{n-4}, \dots$ terms.

It somehow makes sense, but I think you need to formally prove that taking the limit of k before the tower indeed works correctly.

Why can't we just assume that they are just large values of $b$ then BAM! You reveal to the math gods that this was a buildup to the limit.

I'd like to see a proof.  The problem is that $k$ is close to $0$, but the exponential tower is super high which moves it away from $1$. As an example, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(1+\frac{1}{n})} \approx (1+\frac{1}{n}) + e^{\frac{1}{n}} (e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}-1)$.  This process is carried out $n-1$ more times, getting larger each time.

If you use $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ then if $k$ goes to $0$ then the tower virtually disappears. To add to that, you have the $k$ multiplied by everything at the end, so that helps to make everything go to $0$. Apart from that, I have no idea how a formal proof can be constructed
